# What's the best way to assign an array of values to Hash.values

Tags: ruby, hash

How would you assign each element of `[5, 6, 7]` to `row`'s values and make `row` become `{1=>5, 2=>6, 3=>7}`?

```
row = {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>0}
#this following line doesn't work of course
row.values = [5, 6, 7]
#NoMethodError: undefined method `values=' for {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>0}:Hash
row
#I want: {1=>5, 2=>6, 3=>7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row.keys.zip([5, 6, 7]){|kv| row.store(*kv)}
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use `Hash[row.keys.zip([5, 6, 7])]`.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution that works for any length of the array, and makes the index of the element the key in the hash is:

```
Hash[row.each_with_index.map {|elem, i| [i, elem]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [5, 6, 7]
Hash[*array.each_with_index.map{ |elem, idx| [idx + 1, elem]}.flatten]
```

as result

```
{1=>5, 2=>6, 3=>7}
```

Comment: Thanks. maybe I was not clear on my requirement. Updated. But the Hash[*] is handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

```
row = {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>0}
p Hash[*(row.keys.zip([5, 6, 7]).flatten)]

#=> {1=>5, 2=>6, 3=>7}
```